# How to access two tables from different database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How to access two tables from different database in android

I tried various ways, tried attaching the other database

code that i have used

```
SQLiteDatabase db=null;
db=getDatabase().getWritableDatabase();//my current database return with sqllite helper
db.beginTransaction();
db.execSQL("attach database '"+dbFile.getAbsolutePath()+"' as userdb");// i am attaching the other database

db.endTransaction();
```

But failed getting the result..

i get an exception

[attach database '/data/data/test.package/databases/db.test' as userdb] cannot ATTACH database within transaction

Kindly assist with a solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `beginTransaction`/`endTransaction` calls.

(Which are wrong anyway because without a call to `setTransactionSuccessful`, the transaction would be rolled back.)